Jenkins pipeline restart from a stage API
Is there any Rest APIs provided by jenkins to restart from a stage in a pipeline?
I am trying to restart a pipeline from a stage. In UI it is possible using 'restart from stage', but there are no API support for the same.


Using API, it doesn't look to be possible.
In the other hand, Jenkins CLI provides this option :

restart-from-stage : Restart a completed Declarative Pipeline build from a given stage.
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[ip]:[port]/ -auth user:password restart-from-stage -j [JOB_NAME] -s [stage name]

